# Advance JSON deserialize > SQL Insert

Tags: c#, json

I want to Insert JSON Values to a SQL Database.  It is working, but There is an object within the main object, which I cannot seem to retrieve the value.

Here is my JSON code

```
{"items":[{"uid":"b003a6ad8ef543dfbebf3ea2d48a1c33","commStatus":"OK","gateway":{"serialNumber":"CA1331305311005","type":null,"uid":"6b8ca67f3eec46c1a94f535c57dd48a3","imei":"353567040903313","macAddress":null},"subscription":{"identifier":"8927000003268372315","state":"INVENTORY","mobileNumber":null,"networkIdentifier":"655103015669848","uid":"1ba23cc6f6bc4a26b42029e4d5b83d1f","ipAddress":"10.13.14.40","operator":"MTN"},"name":"220"},{"uid":"500ed42280594d5b9a3049db15b6e5c9","commStatus":"OK","gateway":{"serialNumber":"CA1301201391004","type":"GX400","uid":"515334dbf5154911aa019520508b8077","imei":"353567041609349","macAddress":"00:14:3E:11:48:0D"},"subscription":{"identifier":"8927000002300070259","state":"INVENTORY","mobileNumber":null,"networkIdentifier":"655103308678726","uid":"073f0fc7ece240e7807db5bc1538d9ef","ipAddress":"10.13.4.51","operator":"MTN"},"name":"4116"}],"count":380,"size":100,"offset":0}
```

So my first problem is, I have to remove the `{"items":`, otherwise I don't get any values.

1. So how can I modify the code to include the `{"items":`

second problem is: gateway is another object, so anything within gateway, I am unable to receive those values.  I am trying to get the value of serialNumber, but its returning null.

2. So my 2nd Question is how can I get values within another object

Here is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace EMS_AVMS_Retrieval
{
    class Program
    {
    [DataContract]
    class items
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string uid { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string commStatus { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string serialNumber { get; set; }
    }

    //[DataContract]
    //public class Gateway
    //{
    //    [DataMember]
    //    public string serialNumber { get; set; }
    //}
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string json = @"[{"items":[{"uid":"b003a6ad8ef543dfbebf3ea2d48a1c33","commStatus":"OK","gateway":{"serialNumber":"CA1331305311005","type":null,"uid":"6b8ca67f3eec46c1a94f535c57dd48a3","imei":"353567040903313","macAddress":null},"subscription":{"identifier":"8927000003268372315","state":"INVENTORY","mobileNumber":null,"networkIdentifier":"655103015669848","uid":"1ba23cc6f6bc4a26b42029e4d5b83d1f","ipAddress":"10.13.14.40","operator":"MTN"},"name":"220"},{"uid":"500ed42280594d5b9a3049db15b6e5c9","commStatus":"OK","gateway":{"serialNumber":"CA1301201391004","type":"GX400","uid":"515334dbf5154911aa019520508b8077","imei":"353567041609349","macAddress":"00:14:3E:11:48:0D"},"subscription":{"identifier":"8927000002300070259","state":"INVENTORY","mobileNumber":null,"networkIdentifier":"655103308678726","uid":"073f0fc7ece240e7807db5bc1538d9ef","ipAddress":"10.13.4.51","operator":"MTN"},"name":"4116"}],"count":380,"size":100,"offset":0}]";

        //Deserialize the data
        DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<items>));
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json));
        var obj = (List<items>)ser.ReadObject(stream);

        //Loop thrrouch values and save the details into database
        foreach (items p in obj)
        {
            //Create SQL conection to your database here
            using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["my    ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
            {
                // Open your connection
                try
                {
                    cn.Open();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                }
                //Change the table name here
                string sql = "INSERT INTO tempTableAVMSRetrievals (uid, commStatus, serialNumber, retrievalDate) VALUES (@uid, @commStatus, @serialNumber, @retrievalDate)";
                // Create the Command and Parameter objects.
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn))
                {
                    //Loop through the and get of parameter values
                    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uid", p.uid);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@commStatus", p.commStatus);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@serialNumber", "SN");
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@retrievalDate", currentDate);

                    //Execute the query
                    try
                    {
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    catch(Exception e2)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e2.ToString());
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        Environment.Exit(0);
                    }


                }
            }
        }
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a **SQL database** - SQL is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by many database systems, but it's not a database product. Many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know **what database system** (and which version) you're using.... (please update tags accordingly)

Comment: If that'sa valid json then you don't have to remove anything. You just have to deserialize it properly. Use json2csharp.com to have an idea on the model that corresponds to your json string if you are unsure.

Comment: Thanks a million Ephraim!! didn't know about that site and all those additional classes solved it!